# How can I warm up an AppEngine Flex app after a deployment?

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-flexible

It appears that AppEngine standard has a warmup feature to warm up an app after a deployment but I don't see the same feature available for Flex. The readiness & liveness probes also don't work for this since setting the path setting to a custom path inside the application doesn't seem to make the probes actually hit the internal endpoint.

Is there some solution I'm missing other than doing things like manually hitting the endpoints myself after the deployment which won't be very reliable since the calls don't necessarily always round robin to each instance?

Comment: The liveliness and readiness should work. Can you share what you tried and what you saw?

Comment: The probes don't hit my internal endpoint even though I'm changing the path variable to a custom value. My log messages don't appear and the app takes a while to answer to requests after a deployment for the first incoming request. Only time I see the logs is if I actually make a call to it myself manually.

Comment: The customized path configured for the [readiness check](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/reference/app-yaml#readiness_checks) would have to be hit and get a 200 OK response (from your app!) for the instance to be added to the pool. If that doesn't happen I'm unsure how you can hit the instance with a manual request - the instance should not be in the pool receiving requests. Maybe your request handler returns 200 OK even though it doesn't actually perform that init section that the 1st manual request does (for example based on the user identity making the request)?

Answer (score 1):

In App Engine Standard, warmup requests essentially load your app's code into a new instance before any live requests reach that instance. This can happen in the following situations:

- When you redeploy a version of your app.
- When new instances are created due to the load from requests
  exceeding the capacity of the current set of running instances.
- When maintenance and repairs of the underlying infrastructure or
  physical hardware occur

In App Engine Flexible, you can achieve the same result by using the `initial_delay_sec` setting for [liveness checks](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/reference/app-yaml#liveness_checks) in your `app.yaml` file. If you set up its value to give enough time for your code to initialize, the first request coming to that instance will be processed quickly by your already-initialized code.

Comment: I see that the default value for that is 300 seconds and my app is certainly warming up far more quickly than that. But still when the first actual request hits the endpoint, it's clear that it takes a bit to warm up compared to subsequent requests after that. Maybe we're talking about two different things. Looking at the logs, after a fresh deployment no matter how much time passes by, until I make an actual request to my application endpoint, the app itself will not respond quickly until the second request coming to it. The GAE instance may be 'warmed up' but my app itself certainly isn't.